# Clojure: Pattern Matching Based Programming

Tags: clojure

### Context

I apologize for this question being soft / philosophical; it's a set of ideas / observations / intuition that I can't formalize.

I've recently been writing large applications in Clojure, and playing with
  * clojure's match macro
  * rule dispatch systems of (1) moustache and (2) compojure
  * com.cederick's friend for security

What I like about all three -- is that rather than objects having functions, all three involve some explicit form of pattern matching to dispatch what happens next.

### Question

Is there a general programming technique behind this? If so, what is it called? Where else does this pattern show up, and how can I learn more about it?

Thanks!

Comment: You've just seen a tip of an iceberg, not a very clean and consistent implementation of a proper pattern matching-centric approach. In order to get an idea of what this thing is all about, take a look at the Term Rewriting Systems (e.g., http://www.amazon.co.uk/Term-Rewriting-That-Franz-Baader/dp/0521779200). It also worth looking at the Wolfram Mathematica, which is mostly built around this idea.

Comment: Can you recommend a book on Mathematica which demonstrates the full power of term rewriting systems?? Ideally something subtitled "mind stretching recipes with mathematica".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching is currently not part of clojure/core right now, but you can use multimethod, cond, case macro , and the https://github.com/clojure/core.match library.